# How to open a file having other extension than ".txt" in notepad from Qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to open a binary file ".bin" in notepad from Qt by the following code :

```
proc.startDetached("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe" + notepath);
```

notepath is the path of the file declared previously in the code...
And nothing opens...

After using the answer the file opened but it gave all weird signs like shown in the picture below:

[image]

But what I want is to have it encoded in hex like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct way of doing this:

```
QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", {notepath});
```

Comment: it work but when the file is opened it gives all weird signs what I want it to do is to encode this binary file in hex i'll edit some picture in the question

Comment: This is expected behavior, notepad shows data as it can. If you want to view it in HEX, then you need to use another problem (not Notepad), probably some HEX-editor. Or write additional code that will convert file to HEX, then open it, and after closing convert it back

Comment: But those 2 pictures are for the same file both opened by notepad but the encoding is different if you look at the right bottom of the 2 pics you can see the encodings... so how can i change the encoding of notepad via Qt that's the question

Comment: Oh, I see. It's actually text file with written hex code there in UTF-8. But in some cases notepad when started tries to open it as UTF-16 BE, yes?

Comment: Indeed you got that right, so do you know how to change the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: Can you share your .bin file you're trying to open?

Comment: yes of course but how can I share it is their options to share files on stackoverflow?

Comment: just use any file exchange service, fex.net for example

Comment: https://fex.net/s/kctfpa3 you can find the file in this link